# Rainbow option pricing formula under *Bachelier* model

Tags: options, option-pricing, exotics

Let's consider a call on min option on two underlying **arithmetic** Browniation motions $V_t$ and $H_t$ (no drift). Let $P_t$ denotes the price process of the option, $r$ the riskfree rate, $\tau$ the time to maturity, then following the notation and the procedure in [[Stulz, 1982]](https://u.osu.edu/stulz.1/files/2016/05/Options-on-the-Minimum-or-Maximum-q6ixkg.pdf) (eq (3) - (7) in particular), we obtain a similar PDE

$$-P_\tau = r_f(P-P_VV-P_HH)-\frac12(P_{VV}\sigma_V^2+P_{HH}\sigma_H^2+2P_{VH}\rho_{VH}\sigma_V\sigma_H)$$

and the boundry conditions are given by
$$P_T:=(\min(V,H)-F,0)_+$$

It looks like the PDE is a heat PDE. Is there any available literature that has already dealt with this PDE, or even better, already given the explicit pricing formula for the **arithmetic** rainbow option? (Assume constant vol, constant corr etc.)